# Designing Django app with many to many relationship and same model across different apps

Tags: python, django, design-patterns, many-to-many

This is the first time I am working with DJango.
I am little confused about how my model should look.

Use case is:

- There are products.
- There are tags.
- There are users.

There is a many to many relationship between products and tags.
There is a many to many relationship between users and tags.

I have created two apps right now.

- Currently product and tags belong to one app: product
- Another app is usrprofile. And I need to add tags to user profile.

Where should Tag reside? 
And will tag have reference to both product and user?

Code:

**App: Product**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Tag(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='ProductTag')    

class ProductTag(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,null=False)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag,null=False)
```

**APP: UsrProfile**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

Comment: I'd create a third app for tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody can tell you where your `Tag` model should best reside in. It's your choice to structure your apps and models. If you want to establish a many-to-many relationship between `Tag` and `UserProfile`, you can specify it in the `UserProfile` model, for instance:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # ... your other fields ...
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('product.Tag')
```

Note that you have to put the `Tag` model in a string together with a reference to the `product` app as shown above. Otherwise, Django will wrongly assume that your `Tag` model resides in the same app as your `UserProfile` model. Also, the names of your apps should all be lowercase. Further, it's a good style to give your many-to-many fields plural names, i.e. instead of `product` in your `Tag` model use `products`.

By the way, if you don't need to add additional information to your many-to-many relationships, it's not necessary to define an intermediate model such as `ProductTag`.